# Why is a weak variational inequality *equivalent* to a strong variational inequality for a continuous, monotone operator?

Tags: continuity, monotone-functions, variational-analysis

Consider a closed set $Q$, and a continuous monotone operator $g: Q \rightarrow E^*$. Consider the "weak" variational inequality: $$\mbox{find } x^* \in Q: \, g(x)^T (x-x^*) \geq 0, \, \forall x \in Q. $$  Another problem is the "strong " variational inequality: $$\mbox{find } x^* \in Q: \, g(x^*)^T (x-x^*) \geq 0, \, \forall x \in Q. $$  By monotonicity of $g$, $$ (g(x) - g(y))^T(x - y) \geq 0, \, \forall x, y, \in Q.$$  So it is clear to me that the strong variational inequality implies the weak. But [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10107-006-0034-z) paper I'm reading claims that the two are *equivalent*, so the weak also implies the strong. Specifically, it says this is because of continuity of $g$. I'm not able to see how this is the case. Can someone provide any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a famous results which is sometimes called Minty lemma or Linearization lemma. (See also any book about variational inequalities, for example the well-known book *An Introduction to Variational Inequalities and Their Applications* of *Kinderlehrer* and *Stampacchia*, p. 84).

Let us denote the variational inequalities by (1) and (2). If $Q$ is a non-empty, closed and **convex** subset of a **finite-dimensional** Euclidean space $E$, then the continuity of $g: Q \to E$ is sufficient to show that (1) implies (2):

Let $x^* \in Q$ be a solution of (1), and put $x= x^* + t(w-x^*)$, $t\in (0,1]$, where $w\in Q$ is arbitrarily chosen. Since $Q$ is convex (!), $x\in Q$. Now, inserting this element into (1) yields
$$\langle g(x^*+t(w-x^*)), t(w-x^*) \rangle \geq 0.$$
Dividing this inequality by $t$ and then passing to the limit $t\downarrow 0$ yields 
$$ \langle g(x^*), w-x^*\rangle \geq 0, \qquad \text{for every } w\in Q,$$
where we used the fact that $g$ is continuous.

If $E$ is not finite-dimensional, then one has to replace the continuity condition for $g$ by one of the two following (equivalent) conditions:

1. $g:Q \to E^*$ is *continuous on finite-dimensional subspaces* of $E$, that is, for every finite-dimensional subspace $F\subset E$, the restriction of $g$ on $Q\cap F$ is weakly continuous.
2. The real valued function $\mathbf R \to \mathbf R$, $t\mapsto \langle g(u+tv),w\rangle$ is continuous at $0^+$ for every fixed elements $u,v,w\in X$.